# Can't find "Messages" view after update android studio to flamingo version

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-flamingo

Can't find "Messages" view after update android studio to flamingo.

-When try to generate signed apk I got error>>>
Errors while building Bundle file. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.

but I can't find 'Messages' view after Android studio flamingo update